# Unity3d surrogate pairs emoji not appears

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

I am working in a unity project, and I am adding a chat module in it. 
I am facing a problem with emotions as it doesn't appear. I changed the .Net framework of unity to use microsoft .net framework and then used the code that solve the problem inside microsoft .net desktop application

```
 string codePoint = "1F601";
 int code = int.Parse(codePoint, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
 string unicodeString = char.ConvertFromUtf32(code);
```

And the code above solved it and I can see the smily face. But when I use it in unity3d I got the output like that (It separated the surrogate to two parts, the high surrogate and the low surrogate).

```
\ud83d\ude01
```

Is there any solution for this problem or at least a work around.

Thanks.